# ValueError: No axis named Time to Close for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: python, pandas

I have found quite a few similar examples and maybe my issue is I am trying to do this in two steps instead of one. Unfortunately I only know how to do it in two parts so any help on how to either correct as is or merge into one line on code would be great!

I am trying to calculate the time between first and last comments to determine how many days it took to work a case. I would also like to calculate the standard deviation in this new column to identify outliers afterwards (ill deal with that part later, I would just like to get to calculating it for now).

First part works:

```
NewDF['Time to Close'] = NewDF.groupby('InquiryID') \
                                ['CommentCreated'] \
                                .transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days)
```

Second part:

```
NewDF['Standard Deviation'] = NewDF.std('Time to Close')
```

Error returned:

ValueError: No axis named Time to Close for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Thanks for any help you can provide! If a link is more appropriate I could also use some guidance in that way!

Comment: Does `NewDF['Standard Deviation'] = NewDF['Time To Close'].std()` work?

Comment: That did it! Ugh I tried something so close to that, thank you!